# PHP - Check if a foldername exists in the current page url

Tags: php

I would like to use php to check if the current page url has a specific folder name and if so then echo Hello

For example:
Check if the domain below has the word: newyork

```
http://www.domain.com/en/newyork/carrental/
```

As seen above the word newyork exists and therefore I need to echo (hello)

Comment: Please add some details

Comment: See strpos function.

Comment: thanks panther, can you please elaborate, am kind of new to php

Comment: changed link to code as it wasn't meant to be a clickable link

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$res = get_headers ( $url )
if (strpos($res[0],"200 OK")) {

}
```

More detailed information here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Comment: <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'newyork')>0) {{echo "hello";};} ?>

is this correct?

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that this does not take the slashes into account, so if one part of the domain was `newyork-rentals`, maybe because OP adds the name of specific companies to the URL, this would still match and throw the detection off.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, do you need your website page, or remote one? If it is your website - your option is good with  MildlySerious comment. But if you want to parse remote website - you should use $res[0] from my example instead of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']